# How to get "WebKit for GTK+3 1.3.7" headers for ubuntu?

Tags: compilation

i'm trying to compile pidgin on ubuntu (mint 17, actually).

./configure says:

```
"You must have WebKit for GTK+3 1.3.7 or newer development headers"
```

but which ubuntu package contains this version?

i have several packages named "webkit" or "gtk", and i tried to locate and install other versions, but couldn't find it.

i downloaded the pidgin and webkit sources, but i don't know how to connect them.

(the pidgin support registration seems offline -> hence, here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Debian system but perhaps you can do the same :)
First, see what you get with this command on a terminal:

```
aptitude search webkit |grep gtk
```

It will shows you all the packages you can install (or already installed) on your system, linking webkit and gtk.

Then you select the package you need : libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev  in your case (on Debian)

Hope this helped, See you !

Comment: In my case, I had to install the following packages for building pidgin:
_libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev_
_libwebkitgtk-dev_
_libjson-glib-dev_
_libgnome-keyring-dev_
_libqt4-dev_
And I used `./configure --disable-kwallet --disable-plugins`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but checkout [WebKitGTK+](http://www.webkitgtk.org/?page=download). Also [this](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk) can help, do you have run

```
$ Tools/gtk/install-dependencies
```

or the other commands listed on the page?